# UPDATE a table with just ~2000 rows is slow, would LOCK help?

Tags: mysql, locking

RDS Performance Insights tell me `UPDATE foobar SET expire=0` is slow , `foobar` has about 2000 rows and there's an index on `expire`, there needs to be. Now, would it be faster if I did a `LOCK TABLES foobar WRITE` before the `UPDATE`? I feel like `UPDATE` is locking piecemeal which causes the problem.

Alternatively, as a terrible hack, I could imagine doing a CREATE TABLE LIKE ; INSERT - SELECT ; RENAME TABLE series of commands which should be lightning quick...

Comment: Define "slow", please.

Comment: Are you expiring on a time? If so put the expire as a `datetime` can compare against that to retrieve expired/non-expired records. If there's another criteria maybe there's a way to do it without a bulk update. On 2k rows is it even causing a problem?

Comment: Note that dan's technique _totally_ eliminates the `UPDATE`.

Comment: *foobar has about 2000 rows and there's an index on expire, there needs to be.* Total rows amount is 2000 rows... but what is the amount of rows to be updated (matched to `expire != 0`)? if it is above ~100 rows then the index by `expire` will increase updating time and hense it is not needed. *would it be faster if I did a LOCK TABLES foobar WRITE before the UPDATE?* No.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are using InnoDB.

Was that the entire query?  So, you are changing all rows of a 2K-row table?

Why?  Might there be another way to design the schema?  Please describe the task further.  There are several things that come to mind -- and they won't involve such a sluggish action.

How big is the table?  Is that 2000 rows out of a million?  Or 2000 out of 3000.

The query must save the old value of 2000 rows, update 2000 rows, update 2000 rows in the index.  Then later it must toss the saved old row copies.

How big is `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?

If it is a single statement, there is already a `LOCK`.  So don't bark of that tree.

Comment: The table has 2000 rows total, altogether.

Comment: @chx - So, your create-insert-select-rename technique is likely to be faster.